# How do you consecutively spawn objects in unity using instantiate?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite, game-physics

So I want to spawn a sprite over and over again without any gaps. so like after an object spawns, another does to give the illusion that they are joined over and over.

I have no working code currently, so I would love some help.

unity2d and visual studio

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how to place the objects next to each other? Or how to spawn things in quick succession? Or are you asking how to spawn sprites in general?

Comment: "the illusion that they are joined over and over" effect is not clear. If you instantiate a sprite over again and again in the same place, no effect would be appreciated.

Comment: I didn't understand what do mean by " the illusion that they are joined over and over" can you add an image or video to i illustrate? (You might want to use trail renderer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to spawn it next too each other use this:

float timer = 1;

```
Vector2 objPos;

public GameObject prefab;

void Start()
{
    objPos = new Vector2(0, 0);
}

void Update()
{
    timer -= Time.deltaTime;

    if (timer <= 0)
    {
        Instantiate(prefab, objPos, quaternion.identity);

        objPos = new Vector2(objPos.x + 0.5f, this.transform.position.y);

        timer = 1;
    }
}
```

this script places a cube every 1 sec 0.5 int the x forward.